# Using Office 2003 normal.dot in Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2003, microsoft-office-2010

I have a user who I have upgraded from office 2003 to Office 2010. This user relies on his custom auto correct that he built into his normal.dot file for Word 2003. He would not like to have to reenter all 200 of his auto corrects. How can I convert his old Normal.dot file with auto corrects to the new Normal.dotm for Office 2010?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some steps specific to Word 2003 and 2007.  They may also work for 2010.  Information is listed at:  http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wordcreate/thread/0bbde9f4-bc1e-4f1d-a468-67cf6625a51b

Yes, you can transfer Normal.dot template to higher version of word, however this will transfer only auto text entries, and you have to export your macros separately.

**To transfer auto text entries, follow the below steps:**

1. Copy the Normal.dot file to external drive (Floppy or Flash Drive).
2. Paste the Normal.dot file into this directory:

   a. Start -> Run -> type %APPDATA% -> click ok.

   b. Click on Microsoft -> Document Building blocks -> 1033 and copy Normal.dot there.

**To transfer the Macros follow the below steps:**

1. Open word 2003 ->Tools->Macros-> Visual Basic Editor-> Right Click on Macro-> Export.
2. Open word 2007 -> Click on Developer tab-> Visual basic -> Right Click and import the Macros you had exported earlier from Word 2003.

Comment: So any corrections and additions to the Auto Correct entries are not transferred with the Normal.dot when they were if you moved from office 2000 to 2003?

Answer (score 2):

To transfer auto text entries, follow these steps:

1. Copy the Normal.dot file to an external drive (floppy or flash drive).
2. Paste the Normal.dot file into this directory:

   - Start -> Run -> type `%APPDATA%` -> click OK.
3. Click on Microsoft -> Word -> Startup and copy Normal.dot there

This works for me in Office 2010.