# How to change the default Word 2016 style to 97-03

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

How can I set the default Style in Word 2013/2016 to match the default Style in Word 2003?

When moving from 2003 to 2007, Microsoft Word's default Style was changed:

[image]

In Word 2007 and 2010 there was an easy way to set the style back to 97/03 by going to **Styles → Set as default**:

[image]

But, in 2013/2016 that doesn't exist:

[image]

I tried to go to *File → New* and search for 2003, select it and click create:

[image]

I went into *Manage Styles → Set Defaults* I can check *New documents based on this template* -

[image]

**But it doesn't stick!** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found, aside from [changing the default styles individually](https://superuser.com/a/845010/116196)<sup>a great answer!</sup> is to download the Word 2003 template and use it to replace the Normal template.

Go to **File → New** and search for *2003*, select it and click create:

[image]

Now, you must replace the Normal template. Go to **File → Save As → Browse** and change the *Save as Type* to **Word Macro-Enabled Template** and in the address bar type `%appdata%` and navigate to *Microsoft → Templates* and save it as **Normal2** - you won't be able to overwrite `Normal` yet. Close Word.

[image]

Now just use Windows Explorer to Navigate back to `%appdata% - microsoft - templates`, rename `Normal` to `oldNormal` and `Normal2` to `Normal`.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Design' tab, click on Word 2003 and then on Set as Default

[image]

Comment: This does not change the default style.  This just changed the current document's style

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry i misunderstood the question. In that case he just have to click the "Set as Default" button, also in the Design tab.

Comment: You should update your answer to reflect that fact.  Of course you might want to read the question (again) the author already attempted that, and reports it did not work.